# Webbrowser-control exception if tab is not been shown early

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, backgroundworker, tabcontrol

I have button and tabcontrol having some tabs on my form.
There is webbrowser-control on the second tab.
I use a backgroundworker for creating its page.
String:

```
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((s, e) => { webBrowser.DocumentText = "qwerty"; });
```

is in form constructor after InitializeComponent() and just one string:

```
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

in button click handler.
After the run my application on pressing the button I get "Unable to get the window handle for the 'WebBrowser' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported." But  it works correct if I choose the second tab (having webbrowser) before.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread/4271581#4271581)?

Comment: @Jordy I need use exactly backgroundworker, but it looks like I have solved the problem already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping all calls of user interface methods on the same thread solves this problem.
DoWorkEventHandler runs in another thread, but RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler runs in the same thread, so if I put into DoWorkEventHandler only getting the data (forming of webpage) and move setting it to webBrowserAstrHost.DocumentText propetry to RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler, everything works correctly.